# Pattern to fill the entire screen

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Every screen of my app has a common tint. Its not a background. Its a pattern that fills the entire screen and it is top of all the views. You can see the pattern flow continuously from one view to another inside the same screen. And it neither obscures other elements nor participate in event handling.

I tried implementing it with this code in my ViewController.

```
UIColor* texture = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Texture.png"]];
UIView* tintView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[tintView setBackgroundColor:texture];
[tintView setAlpha:0.5];
[self.view addSubview:tintView];
```

But it doesn't pass on touches to the views behind it.

`tintView` shouldn't participate in any event handling. Rather it should let other elements behind it, handle the events like they do it normally.

Other way of doing it is set this as a background of the `view` property of a UIViewController and set a common alpha for all other subviews of `view` to show the pattern behind. That will be redundant in most ways.

Any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your tintView a subclass of `UIView` and implement the [`hitTest:withEvent:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) method, returning nil. This will make your view transparent to touches. Or set `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO`.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `background color` with a `Textured image`

```
UIImage *bgimg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Texture.png"];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:bgimg];
```